# Ubuntu - chroot virtual system for ssh/ftp user

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ssh, chroot

I have a webserver running Ubuntu 11.10
I just store a copy of my projects' sources, but now I'm thinking to allow a user to access via SSH the system. I'd like to create such a virtual machine, in order to protect my sources from that user.

I was thinking to use virtualbox, but it's not the best solution (because of the heavy ram need), so I was thinking maybe I could do this using chroot.

How can I do?
Suppose I've created a system user called "test1" (/home/test1) how can I prevent him from browsing outside its home directory?
I'll allow test1 to access via ssh and ftp (vsftpd).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might have completed this already.
But here is the link to an article which explains setting up chrooted account.

http://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 0):

Backup your vsftpd.conf file

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.bak
```

Open vsftpd.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Assuming you haven't modified the default file change these settings:

Keep the chroot_local_user=YES **commented** (It will be at two places)

Uncomment chroot_list_enable=YES

and Uncomment chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

Now create vsftpd.chroot_list file under /etc:

```
sudo touch vstftp.chroot_list
```

Edit this file to add your user "test1" (Assuming your user already exists: which means you should be able to traverse to /home/test1 directory). Add each user on one line

test1

test2

....

Restart vsftpd:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Though you might have already resolved this, I tried to search for this but could not google it...I accidentally figured this out...hence posting it